# type equivalence of structures in c

Tags: type-equivalence

which of the following "structures" are `structure-equivalent`?

```
struct abd0{
  int x;
  float y;
};

struct abd1{
  float y;
  int x;
};

struct abd2{
 float x;
 int x;
};
```

Can there be any case where name equivalence exists and structural equivalence does not?